# Use a webhook to send a message as someone else

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I've been looking into this issue, but only found webhooks that copy the author's name and avatar. I'd like to do the same, but with a tagged member's stuff.

trigger:
`--say @test test`

result:
`@test test`

This is my code so far:

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def say(ctx, *, message: str, member: discord.Member = None):
    async with ClientSession() as session:
        webhook = discord.Webhook.from_url(WEBHOOK_URL, adapter=discord.AsyncWebhookAdapter(session))
        await webhook.send(content=message, username=member.Member.name, avatar_url=member.avatar_url)
```

Comment: For clarity, you want the command to copy the tagged member's name & avatar and post a message with the webhook's picture and name mirroring that of the tagged user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example of "impersonating" a user through a webhook, it takes the user's name and their profile picture but simply appears as a bot. It's the same method as bots such as "NQN" uses.

```py
@client.command()
async def say(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, message=None):

        if message == None:
                await ctx.send(
                    f'Please provide a message with that!')
                return

        webhook = await ctx.channel.create_webhook(name=member.name)
        await webhook.send(
            str(message), username=member.name, avatar_url=member.avatar_url)

        webhooks = await ctx.channel.webhooks()
        for webhook in webhooks:
                await webhook.delete()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@client.command()
async def impersonate(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, message=None):

        if message == None:
                await ctx.send(f'Who do you want to impersonate?')
                return

        webhook = await ctx.channel.create_webhook(name=member.name)
        await webhook.send(
            str(message), username=member.name, avatar_url=member.avatar_url)

        await webhook.delete()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).